# Microsoft ASP.NET Core Multiple Security and Microsoft ASP.NET Core Spoofing Vulnerabilities

Tags: asp.net-core

We have ASP.Net core vulnerabilities in few of my Application (MIM) servers.These are the listed vulnerabilities

Microsoft ASP.NET Core Denial Of Service Vulnerability May 2019

AND

Microsoft ASP.NET Core Spoofing Vulnerabilities

The vulnerabilities was pointing to C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0

To fix this,I have  uninstalled 2.0.0 dotnet version and installed the latest SDK "dotnet-sdk-2.2.401-win-x64", Now the above vulnerability has been disappeared.Now its pointing to below results.
    "20c2d01092d9a1b7a583fe99a50b15686e2b7de92.2.7fbe49b396bf8fgh2998791dedca487e510e2619c2.2.3cbe8559e49042e96694008077e30454c02.1.336c2d01092d9a1b7a200fe99a50e15686e2b7de92.2.55cb615fcbe8559e49042e96694008088e30454c0396bf8ece2934567dedcq487e581e2619c2.2.3#"

Upon checking I found few 2.0.0 related files under below folder, that causing the issue again here.

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder

Can anyone suggest me what all steps need to taken care for fixing the issue completely ?

Comment: What was the exception or error?

Comment: Please see the updated description